# Python - Matplotlib / matplotlib.cbook.TimeoutError: LOCKERROR

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I faced this problem when I installed module `matplotlib` and wrote this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

And then here is the error:

```
"matplotlib.cbook.TimeoutError: LOCKERROR: matplotlib is trying to acquire the lock
'C:\\Users\\Андрей\\.matplotlib\\.matplotlib_lock-*'
and has failed. This maybe due to any other process holding this
lock. If you are sure no other matplotlib process is running try
removing these folders and trying again."
```

So of course if it can not be imported it can not be used.

Comment: The error message has provided some ideas as to why this has happened. Have you tried to implement its suggestion?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. This is to mention that this question does not concern numpy, so please avoid using the numpy tag.

Answer (score 12):

Try deleting the folder .matplotlib

for you it is in

C:\Users\Андрей\.matplotlib

Then import the python module.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux the answer above also works, but the folder to be deleted is under  `/home/user/.cache/matplotlib`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you did install LaTex (there are many different ways of doing it depends on your OS). First, try to erase $ sign before and after ( from '$ axes given name $' to 'axes given name'). If it will not work just delete that file (which is not .text) and rerun a whole process again. But make sure that you reloaded your initial commands such as "import numpy as np", "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt" and if you are 3D ploting "from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D". If you already have LaTex on your PC/LapTop then reinstall it and do it again. It should help you

Comment: Remember that you should not delete a whole Folder because Python may not to make a new folder: as a result, it may give you a new error. Stay Safe

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have two different matplotlibs on your computer. So, good advice was provided upper by Haxoit (it also worked for me): just delete the folder with matplotlib (you can find the path of it in the error message.