# python: running two matplotlib processes in the same folder

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.6, cluster-computing

I run multiple instances of python in the same folder. I am working on an interactive cluster. I send ~10 batch processes that run `matplotlib` and produce figures, and I also want to run an interactive `ipython` session (also producing figures). When working interactively, I got the following error, and also one of my batch process failed due with the same message. I don't understand why this error happens when working interactively and I am used to send multiple processes that generate figures and they not interact with each other. Also, I think there have been an update on the cluster itself, because now I am generating figures in batch jobs with `TkAgg` backends, whereas this generated an error and failure in the past.

```
TimeoutError: LOCKERROR: matplotlib is trying to acquire the lock
    '/<home>/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/.matplotlib_lock-*' 
and has failed.  This maybe due to any other process holding this
lock.  If you are sure no other matplotlib process is running try
removing these folders and trying again.
```

EDIT:

matplotlib version: 2.2.2

Comment: If you are not using multiprocessing, maybe[this](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7776/#issuecomment-271476526) suggestion helps? That's from 2017 though, and that specific issue should be fixed in newer versions - so if you are not on an old version, it might not help

Comment: @lucidbrot I really do not understand the solution, if you can explain it to me. Each batch job is running on a dedicated node, and the interactive job is running on the log-in node

Comment: The way I understand it is that (at least in that old version from 2017) matplotlib uses a folder for some caching and locks it to make sure nobody else uses it at the same time. Seems to have to do with tex, in that linked issue at least. A workaround is to tell it to use a different folder for each program you're running. By specifying such a folder in an environment variable before the command. i.e. your normal `python something.py` becomes `MPLCONFIGDIR=/some/folder python something.py`. No guarantee that this (still) works, but worth a try

Comment: it would make sense to check what version of matplotlib you're using. What does `python -c "import matplotlib as m; print(m.__version__)"`say?

Comment: Another thing that might have happened is that a lockfile remained when your process was killed for some reason. If that was the case, [deleting the cace/lockfile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50486999/2550406) should work. But that would be a one-time solution - if the issue persists, this is not the solution.

Comment: Since this is (La)TeX related: do you need the LaTeX rendering, or can you do with Matplotlib's built-in `mathtext`? Also, do you need to create the images on the nodes (e.g., you are trying to create a 10-minute high-resolution movie of sorts), or can you just take a bit longer and run the figure creation just on a single node, the front-end node, or even locally on your desktop or laptop?

Comment: @lucidbrot indeed, I have removed the file and now it works. Could you clarify why this happened? I am very confused, only one of my batch file failed, and others completed successfully

Comment: @00 I think I would do this as a workaround. I am still wondering if there is a way to avoid this, for convenience

Comment: @simona I can only guess, but: perhaps when one of your runs failed, it crashed without removing the lockfile. The lockfile is like a warning flag though: matplotlib will not work in that cache if another process is working in it at the same time - so it waits until the warning flag disappears and if that takes too long it fails. The warning flag never disappears though, because the process who created it (and would normally remove it again) crashed in between. Now question is whether it works now consistently (good), or if you have to remove it again every time before you run it (not good).